# Is there a way in python not to generate (nan*j) when calculating (1/0+0j) in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, inf

I am new to python and I am converting some of Matlab scripts to Python.
I reached this issue when dealing with complex arrays with numpy when I need to get the reciprocal of the array elements.
If the element is 0+0j then the reciprocal is: 1/(0+0j)= inf+nanj.
example:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[6+2j, 6], [0, 4]])
print(array1)
reciprocal_array = 1/array1
print(reciprocal_array)
```

However, in Matlab the result of 1/(0+0j) is only **inf** but here in python the imaginary NAN makes a problem for me. I need these imaginary NAN (nanj) not to be there. Are there any solution not to have them?

I found a way to get rid of nanj in the reciprocal array after I generate it but I am asking if there is more feasible solutions.

```
where_are_nans = np.isnan(array1 )
array1[where_are_nans] = np.inf
```

Comment: whats wrong with the solution you have?

Comment: @anon01 If you mean with the 2nd code section I shared, I am not sure if this solution adds more burdens to the code execution (checking all the elements in all different dimensions and then replace the nan elements with inf) since I am dealing with large arrays. Or there may be other way to do deal with this !

Answer (score 0):

Your sample array:

```
In [34]: array1
Out[34]: 
array([[6.+2.j, 6.+0.j],
       [0.+0.j, 4.+0.j]])
```

Make 2 arrays from this:

```
In [35]: out = np.full_like(array1, np.inf+0j)    
In [36]: out
Out[36]: 
array([[inf+0.j, inf+0.j],
       [inf+0.j, inf+0.j]])

In [37]: cond = array1!=0    
In [38]: cond
Out[38]: 
array([[ True,  True],
       [False,  True]])
```

Your divide can also be expressed with the `divide` ufunc:

```
In [39]: 1/array1
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_964\2387133254.py:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  1/array1
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_964\2387133254.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  1/array1
Out[39]: 
array([[0.15      -0.05j, 0.16666667+0.j  ],
       [       inf +nanj, 0.25      +0.j  ]])

In [40]: np.divide(1,array1)
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_964\2318703765.py:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  np.divide(1,array1)
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_964\2318703765.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  np.divide(1,array1)
Out[40]: 
array([[0.15      -0.05j, 0.16666667+0.j  ],
       [       inf +nanj, 0.25      +0.j  ]])
```

The `ufunc` takes a `where` parameter, telling it where to do the division.  It also needs an `out` array, telling it what to use else where:

```
In [41]: np.divide(1,array1,where=cond, out=out)
Out[41]: 
array([[0.15      -0.05j, 0.16666667+0.j  ],
       [       inf+0.j  , 0.25      +0.j  ]])
```

This both gives the desired result, and avoids the warnings.

Comment: this is a useful  suggestion. thx